# In AngularJS can you automatically bind an onclick function from the object you're generating when using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of items and Im using ng-repeat to create an element for each item in the array. One of the attributes on each item could possibly be a function, like this:

```
item.myFunction = function(){
// do something
}
```

Can I bind this to an element using an onclick or ng-click or something? I have tried the following:

```
<p onclick="{{item.myFunction}}">click me</p>

<p ng-click="{{item.myFunction}}">click me</p>

<p ng-attr-onclick="{{item.myFunction}}">click me</p>
```

Am I trying to achieve something that isn't possible? Can't find any help on google.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this possible, but you could try implementing a wrapper function that will call your specific object function:

```
<p ng-click="{{myFunction(item)}}">click me</p>
```

Then implement the function like this in your controller:

```
myFunction(item){ item.myFunction() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the object to the click function and do the same,

**Controller:**

```
$scope.myFunction = function(someObject){
// do something
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p ng-click="{{myFunction(item)}}">click me</p>
```

Working [`SampleApp`](https://plnkr.co/edit/4cjrUcG9ysvlx5yP9jlk?p=preview)